# Django: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist error when trying to make custom form

Tags: python, django, forms, registration

hey all i'm trying to make a custom registration form. The problem is, I try to register someone, and I get the error that related object does not exist, and i have no idea why. Here is in my views.py:

```
form = RegistrationForm()
if request.method=="POST":
    if request.POST['action']=="register":
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

Here is the RegistrationForm() in forms.py:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

    fname = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'First Name','required':True}))
    lname = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Last Name','required':True}))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=256, label="Email", required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Email','required':True, 'type':'email'}))
    emailConfirm = forms.EmailField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Confirm Email','required':True, 'type':'email'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Password','required':True}))
    password2 =forms.CharField(required=False)

    biography = forms.CharField(label = "Biography",required=False)
    research_place = forms.CharField(label="Research Place",required=False)
    studies = forms.CharField(label="Studies",required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = RegisterUser
        fields = ('email','emailConfirm','password1','biography','research_place','studies')
    def save(self,commit=True):
        RegisterUser = super(RegistrationForm,self).save(commit=False)
        RegisterUser.first_name=self.cleaned_data['fname']
        RegisterUser.last_name=self.cleaned_data['lname']
        RegisterUser.biography=self.cleaned_data['biography']
        RegisterUser.research_place="Def"
        RegisterUser.studies="Def"
        print (RegisterUser.studies)

        if commit:
            print("hurr")
            RegisterUser.save()
        return RegisterUser
```

And my models.py:

```
class RegisterUser(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    biography = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
    research_place = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
    studies = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)


    def set_password(self, raw_password):
        self.user.set_password(raw_password)
    USERNAME_FIELD='email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['fname', 'lname','password1']
    is_active=False
```

And finally admin.py:

```
class RegisterInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = RegisterUser
    can_delete = False

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (RegisterInline, )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

please let me know what I am doing wrong, and if there is anything else I should change. Thanks so much!

Full trace:
Traceback:

```
File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/src/SignUp/views.py" in lOut
  122.                      form.save()
File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/src/SignUp/forms.py" in save
  48.       RegisterUser = super(RegistrationForm,self).save(commit=False)
File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in save
  93.         user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/src/SignUp/models.py" in set_password
  38.       self.user.set_password(raw_password)
File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in __get__
  608.                 "%s has no %s." % (self.field.model.__name__, self.field.name)
```

Errro in terminal: "POST /out HTTP/1.1" 500 82901

Exception Location: /Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py in **get**, line 608

Comment: Please add the full stack trace to you question.

Comment: @arctelix i added it

Comment: There does not seem to be any special reason you are overriding `set_password` in your `RegisterUser` model.  Try removing that and let me know if you still get an error.

Comment: @arctelix then it says RegisterUesr does not have set_password   'RegisterUser' object has no attribute 'set_password'

Comment: Ok, almost there..  Add your set_password method back in and  modify the line in RegistrationForm `RegisterUser = super(RegistrationForm,self).save()` we took out `commit=false`

Comment: @arctelix ok "register user has no user" is the error now

Comment: need the full stack trace please and error message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105400/discussion-between-arctelix-and-swedishfished).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django will automatically add all the User fields from UserCreationForm. So you just need to add your custom stuff. The most significant issue was in your Meta.model and your save method.

Replace RegistrationForm:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    biography = forms.CharField(label = "Biography",required=False)
    research_place = forms.CharField(label="Research Place",required=False)
    studies = forms.CharField(label="Studies",required=False)

    class Meta:
        # This tells Django to perform all the user actions and the standard
        # user model.  It does not care about RegisterUser.
        model = User
        fields =('email','emailConfirm','password1','biography','research_place','studies')

    def save(self,commit=True):
        # you were redefining RegisterUser before
        # First we need to save the user model,  we use a variable to work  
        # with the user instance.
        user = super(RegistrationForm,self).save(commit=False)
        user.username = user.email
        user.save()

        # Now we can save your custom RegisterUser
        r_user = RegisterUser(user=user,
                      biography=self.cleaned_data['biography'], 
                      research_place=self.cleaned_data['research_place'], 
                      studies=self.cleaned_data['studies'])
        if commit:
            r_user.save()
            print ('saving user: %s' % self.user)

        # We return the new RegisterUser instance which contains the user
        return r_user
```

Clean up model:

```
class RegisterUser(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    biography = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
    research_place = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
    studies = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)

    # None of the stuff you had below is required
```